# How do i redirect result(Which will have some data of request and response) to another jsf page using ExternalContext?

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, externalcontext

```
public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    logger.debug("Entering in DirectPayPaymentResponseHandler handleRequest() method");
    logger.debug("responseParameter="
            + request.getParameter("responseParameter"));
    logger.debug("responseparams=" + request.getParameter("responseparams"));
    String respParams = request.getParameter("responseparams");

    try{
      boolean flag=processRequest(respParams);
      if(flag){
        //response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/customer/Success.xhtml");            
      } else {
        //response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/customer/Failure.xhtml");        
      }
    } catch(Exception e){
        logger.fatal("Error:- "+ e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are looking for a way to forward the request (ExternalContext is available in jsf, not servlets). A simple way to do that would be

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/path/filename.xhtml");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

This will not cause a second request from the browser like sendRedirect() does and keep all information sent available for further inspection.